# npm: How to create debug and production builds with the correct dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, npm

I am building a single page app which uses typescript and a few other dependencies (jquery, immutable, lodash, react, ...). The different resulting modules are included with requirejs.

I want to create both debug and production builds, where the debug builds should include the debug builds of the dependencies (i.e. non-minified, with debug checks (e.g. for React)) and the production builds should include the minified production builds of the dependencies.

How can I do this with npm (no grunt, gulp, etc. please)?

Comment: IMHO you can't do that only with `npm`. Because `npm` will just install the content the maintainer of the package published.

Comment: But quite often the maintainers publish both debug and production builds. In reacts case, for example, they differ by more than just minification ... oh wait, I'll just look at how they do it ...

Comment: oh well... they use grunt.js. But is that really necessary?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. `npm`, `bower` , ... are just there it install the packages and their dependencies and keep them up to date. It is up to you to create a `grunt`, `glup`, ... workflow that will combine/minify/modify the script/files in the way you want them.

Comment: Well, one could just use the 'scripts' part in the package.json file instead ... what I am wondering about is how the build process would pickup the right dependencies, I guess....

Comment: Sure, but you always need to add some additional logic with external script (plain js file, grunt, gulp, ...) to `npm`, even if it is called directly by `npm` after the installation/update, because `npm` itself does just provide help for that. You might achieve it without directly calling those scripts, but you will still require them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any external build tool/task runner based on plugins (such as grunt or gulp) you could do everything just using your modules' CLI and [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts). Note that this way requires more knowledge about your OS environment such as [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) and of course you should be very familiar with node itself because you may need to write some wrappers for build tasks.

NPM scripts supports various hooks that can be used to separate development and production processes. For example, `preinstall` could be used to build a development release and `prepublish` for production and deploy.

There is pretty useful article by Keith Cirkel "[How to Use npm as a Build Tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)". Check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've actually already read the article, I guess my question is how can I use one dependency or the other elegantly depending on which thing I want to build. I would think that this is a common problem and that there should be an option in npm, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I think it could be done elegantly using flags or `NODE_ENV`, remember `npm install --production` which installs only production dependencies.

Comment: Broken link to Keith's article?

Comment: link to Keith article. https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/